# HERE route api plugins QGIS

Tags: here-api

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/rvbartolata/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-here-api-plugin\ui\routematching\dialog_routematching.py", line 88, in process_res
start_points = list(map(lambda x: x[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"][0], features_list))
File "C:/Users/rvbartolata/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-here-api-plugin\ui\routematching\dialog_routematching.py", line 88, in
start_points = list(map(lambda x: x[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"][0], features_list))
IndexError: list index out of range

i try to import in plugin my existing points that error appear also i try it to create the dummy points its the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to report the issue within the following link for getting in touch with the developers directly since HERE does not officially provide support for the plugins developed by a third party:
https://github.com/MIERUNE/qgis-here-api-plugin/issues

However, we would be happy to provide best-effort support. First things first, please check if the plugin that you mentioned is the following one:
[HERE Route API Plugin for QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF7md.png)

We cannot replicate the issue or even cannot use the plugin for the following error of missing the layer options as the following screenshot shows:
[Cannot select Layer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhyrn.png)
How about you? Did you follow the instructions below and can select layer options after configuring your API key?
https://github.com/MIERUNE/qgis-here-api-plugin

Last but not least, since the plugin is said to be using the HERE Route Matching API, you can check the API detail direct at the following place:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/topics/gps-speeding-alerts.html
For example, could you try sending the following request and see if you can get a valid response from the HERE Route Matching API directly?

```
curl --location 'https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/match/routelinks?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&attributes=SPEED_LIMITS_FCn(FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT%2CTO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT)%2CLINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(ISO_COUNTRY_CODE)&apiKey=your_api_key&waypoint0=25.306454%2C55.365857'
```

Notice, you need to replace the API key placeholder of your_api_key with your own key before sending the request out.